# -Wformat-truncation error writing 2-3 bytes into region of 2-6 bytes

Tags: c++, gcc, directive, format-truncation

I have an issue with the following fuction:

```
std::string TimeToTimestampStr(time_t t)
{
    tm aTm;
    ACE_OS::localtime_r(&t, &aTm);
    //       YYYY   year
    //       MM     month (2 digits 01-12)
    //       DD     day (2 digits 01-31)
    //       HH     hour (2 digits 00-23)
    //       MM     minutes (2 digits 00-59)
    //       SS     seconds (2 digits 00-59)
    char buf[20];
    snprintf(buf, 20, "%04d-%02d-%02d_%02d-%02d-%02d",
             (aTm.tm_year+1900)%10000,
             (aTm.tm_mon+1)%13,
             aTm.tm_mday%32,
             aTm.tm_hour%24,
             aTm.tm_min%60, // warning on this parameter
             aTm.tm_sec%60);
    return std::string(buf);
}
```

```
error: ‘%02d’ directive output may be truncated writing between 2 and 3 bytes into a region of size between 2 and 6 [-Werror=format-truncation=]
```

Not sure why this is an issue, 2-3 bytes should not be truncated in a region of size 2-6 bytes, so what is the reason for the warning? Best guess is that 3 bytes could be truncated by the lower limit of the region (2)? But that's complete bogus - region is of size up to 6 bytes, and should only truncate if more than 6 bytes are being written.... right?

EDIT: other questions I found were related to writing more bytes to a region of less bytes, which led be to adding % to enforce the upper size limit of input.

Comment: while you activate warning about *format-truncation* you will have that warning. It does not say your code is wrong, it says you truncate including when you explicitly truncate. There is similar cases out of *format-truncation*. I think also it is strange to have that warning when the truncation is explicit, to have when implicit ok, but implicit is the best way to 'force'  us to ask gcc to not produce them, so strange

Comment: If you mean truncating via % activates the warning, then I believe you are mistaken. Truncating explicitly allowed me to get rid of the truncation warning at position 2: `aTm.tm_mon+1`. The question is - why doesn't it work at position 5: `aTm.tm_min%60`?

The project makefile enables the warning, and the build fails because of the warning. I can't remove the gcc flag, so I have to find a way to solve the warning.

Thanks!

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: yes. forgot to mark as answer, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `tm` the fields are `int` so there are *signed*, for the compiler all the numbers you compute can be negative, but you sized your array supposing there are all positive because you know what `localtime_r` does, but for the compiler 26 bytes are necessary because the worst case is like `-9999--13--31_-23--59--59`

Of course having the size 20 there is no undefined behavior because you use `snprintf` rather than `printf`, but for instance compiling with `-Wall` activate the production of the warning

Replace the size 20 by at least 26 and you will not have the warning

Comment: Investigation shows that warning can be "fixed" if return value from snprintf is processed:
`auto written = snprintf(buf, 20, ...);
if (written >= 20) {
   // Error processing
}`
https://godbolt.org/z/sTcczxzrE